# Windows Server 2012 Essentials questions

Tags: windows-server-2012

Two questions, which hopefully will be easy for you experienced users.

I just purchased a used Dell server with Windows Server 2012 Essentials on it.  I noticed that the [Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2012#Editions) states it has a 25 user limit.  What, exactly, does that mean?  I'll be running this as a web server, does this mean I can have no more than 25 different users connecting to the website simultaneously?

Also, is there any limit to how many *different* websites I can put on this server?  Not in terms of needing more space or RAM or anything, I'm just wondering if IIS8 has some kind of built in limitation that I need to be aware of.  I'm assuming it doesn't, but it's better to ask than to assume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user limit is for CAL's. A website technically only uses one user, whichever one you have the website run as. This OS should be fine for a small webserver.

Answer (score 1):

Web server connections are web workloads and do not consume CALs

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/volume-licensing/2014/03/10/licensing-how-to-when-do-i-need-a-client-access-license-cal/

This is the specific section relating to Web Servers.

So if it is the front end you don't need a CAL but if it is a back end process running on the server itself then yes you do.

I hope that is helpful

Yours

Ed